# Want the code for button click in web driver

Tags: selenium, web

What is the selenium web driver syntax for button click? my code is

```
<input class="btn btn-primary" type="button" value="Register"
    href="/home/pages/home#/register" ng-click="register($event)">
```

the code which i have wrote has not working..

Comment: What does "not working" mean? An error message? We need to know the message.

Answer (score 1):

This is write in Java using Selenium 2

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input.btn.btn-primary")).click();
```

or

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input[value='Register']")).click();
```

but if you have a lot of button with the same class or value, i suggest that you add a condition like

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input.btn.btn-primary[value='Register']")).click();
```